# list association for many_to_many not saved in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :clubs
accepts_nested_attributes_for :clubs

class Club < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :users

class UsersClubs < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

In my users controler I have specified:

```
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:club_ids => [])
end
```

In my form I have:

```
<%= select_tag :club_ids, options_from_collection_for_select(@Club.all, "id", "name"), :multiple=>true%>
```

Once I click form submit I see that club_ids is being sent with the values from the select form, nevertheless when I call `user.update(user_params)` it is not adding them to the database. I've looked at other examples and made my changes accordingly but it still doesn't work. What am I missing?

EDIT: I know that I can do the inserts and deletes myself because I am receiving an array populated with the values that I want, so I can insert the corresponding records. I was just wondering if rails did this automatically through updating params.

Comment: params.require(:user).permit(:club_ids), not sure but try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try putting `:club_ids => []` inside a hash.

eg.

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit({:club_ids => []})
end
```

referenced from [here](https://coderwall.com/p/_1oejq)

Comment: This made no difference.

Comment: Have you tried:

`<%= select_tag "user[club_ids][]", options_from_collection_for_select(@Club.all, "id", "name"), :multiple=>true%>` ?

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue, the name of the tag.